# How to change the background color to white in WebGL with textures

Tags: animation, canvas, html5-canvas, webgl, texture2d

Learning my way around WebGL but can't figure out how to change a simply background from black to white in this. It appears that this

`gl.clearColor(255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 1.0);`

does indeed change the background color to white, BUT as soon as the animation loads it updates the background back to black.

I'm stumped here. How do you change the background color to white and keep it from changing back to black?

The simplest way i can share what i'm doing is this example on codepen. if you can tell me how (and hopefully why) to change the background color on this codepen then you would help me significantly.

https://codepen.io/laxminegi/pen/xxYBOMj

Comment: You have to add the code to the question. Links to external resources tend to break or the content may change. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**."*

Comment: I believe my question is pretty easy to understand for someone who has worked with WebGL. If I add code to this question it would be the entire code from the link I added and that seems more confusing. If you click the link and follow what I’ve tried to do you’ll see what I’m talking about